# Meaning of "Оставайтесь инкогнито" in this context

Tags: значения

I'm looking for someone to help me understand an exchange I had on Instagram. I studied Russian about 13 years ago and have been trying to practice recently. I followed some Instagram accounts for dogs in Russia.

Edit: Note I'm not talking about a dog. It was in reference to pictures of dinner.

The exchange

Me: "это выглядит аппетитно"

Them :"спасибо, а вы у нас кто?"

Me : "Я никто"

Them :"ну и ладненько"

Me: "Извенинте. Я здесь толко для того, чтобы посмотреть на таксу."

Them: "Оставайтесь инкогнито"

инкогнито looks like a transliteration of incognito from English but in English, this basically only means to remain in secret. Is this in reference to not saying who I was?

Comment: Please note that while the meaning is the same, pronunciation slightly differs: in Russian,  stress falls on the first O, not on the last I as in English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Russian *инкогнито* means pretty much the same as English "incognito": "concealing one's real identity".

It's not a transliteration of the English word: both words have been borrowed independently.

*Оставайтесь инкогнито* literally means "stay incognito", implying "OK, don't disclose your real identity if you don't want to".

Comment: Thanks, how do you get your font like that btw?

Comment: @RyanHowe: it's italic, enclose the word in single underscores or asterisks: `_инкогнито_` or `*инкогнито*`

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a straight out of dictionary question.

[incognito](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/incognito) - "with the real identity concealed"

```
Me : "Я никто" / "I am noboby"

...

Them: "Оставайтесь инкогнито" / "[So] Stay nobody"
```